# Old code to define \@part in scrbook does not work with TeX Live 2014 and I need a replacement

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, parts

I have to compile an old book from 2007 which uses `scrbook` (from KOMA-script v3.12) and redefines the part page. The definition of `\@part` does not work any more (TL 2014), though. Here's a minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, german, twoside, openright, headings=small, bibliography=totoc, footinclude=false, mpinclude=false, headinclude, captions=tableheading, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty, index=totoc
%, draft
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     %Trenngen, Schriftsatz; Neues Deutsch

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        %Umlaute, Sonderzeichen...
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Dateicodierung: Unter Linux latin1 anstatt ansinew verwenden

\makeatletter
% 
\let\size@partnumber\Huge

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \@maybeautodot\thepart%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \noindent
    \hfill
    \partmark{#1}%
    {\@parskipfalse\@parskip@indent%\centering
     %\interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont\sectfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \size@partnumber\partformat
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \noindent\size@part \flushright{#2}\strut\par}%
    \@endpart}
\begin{document}
\part{Einführung in wichtige Aspekte und Phänomene der Strömungsmechanik}

\noindent
Im Teil A dieses Buches soll zunächst anhand konkreter Beispiele aus Natur und Technik gezeigt werden, ...
\end{document}
```

The desired outcome should look like this:

[image]

but instead I get the following error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@part ...nt \hfill \partmark {#1}{\@parskipfalse 
                                              \@parskip@indent \normalfo...
l.39 ...pekte und Ph�nomene der Str�mungsmechanik}

! Undefined control sequence.
\@part ...rk {#1}{\@parskipfalse \@parskip@indent 
                                              \normalfont \sectfont \ifn...
l.39 ...pekte und Ph�nomene der Str�mungsmechanik}
```

There actually are three pages of output:

- A part page with the part title,
- followed by an empty page,
- followed by a page with the introductory text.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for something like that:

```
\documentclass[10pt, german, twoside, openright, headings=small, bibliography=totoc, footinclude=false, mpinclude=false, headinclude, captions=tableheading, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty, index=totoc
%, draft
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin 1]{inputenc}

\setkomafont{partnumber}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}
\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{20pt}%
  Im Teil A dieses Buches soll zunächst anhand konkreter Beispiele aus Natur und Technik gezeigt werden, ...
}
\part{Einführung in wichtige Aspekte und Phänomene der Strömungsmechanik}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setpartpreamble` is apparently not necessary, when I just add the introduction after `\part{}` it is where it should be.

Comment: @Christoph You need `partpreamble`, otherweise you get the text on a new page. `part` is meant to be alone on the page, no additional text.

Comment: [from earlier today](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24749212#24749212)